# Is there a way for me to write a program that displays all the possible combinations for any four numbers entered by the user

Tags: vb.net

This is what I have so far. I'm just struggling for what to put in the `For` loop?

```
    Module Module1
    
        Sub Main()

            Dim num1, Num2, Num3, Num4 As Byte
    
            Console.WriteLine("What number do you want to enter")
            num1 = Console.ReadLine()
    
            Console.WriteLine("What number do you want to enter")
            Num2 = Console.ReadLine()
    
            Console.WriteLine("What number do you want to enter")
            Num3 = Console.ReadLine()
    
            Console.WriteLine("What number do you want to enter")
            Num4 = Console.ReadLine()
    
            For i = 1 To 24
    
            Next

            Console.ReadKey()

        End Sub

    End Module
```

Comment: Of cour5se there's a way to do that, but it's not for us to do it for you or teach you from scratch. Apply some brain power. How would you do it if you had to do it manually? That's exactly the same logic that you would use in code, so work out that logic first, then write code to implement it. The logic is nothing to do with programming so you don't need programming experience to do it. When you've actually made an effort and implemented something, post a question here if and when you encounter an actual issue.

Comment: You're going to be luck to find someone willing to write the implementation for you.  What part of the combination calculations are you struggling with exactly?

Comment: I'd use the [Combinatorics](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G) library.  You need variations without repetition.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: yes, there is a way. ;)